# How do I delete invalid Firebase messaging token with Js-SDK?

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging

I can't use `firebase.messaging().deleteToken()` (404 - Request entity not found). How do I get a new token?
`firebase.app().delete()` also doesn't clear messaging token.
Do I have to delete the indexedDB record by myself?